# Is my python path correct?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-14.04

I have python 3.4 installed into a virtualenv and I am using django 1.7 with apache 2 with mod_wsgi. When encountering an error (the error is irrelevant to the question) I saw the following python path in the error message:

```
Python Path:    
['/var/www/buchhaltung',
 '/home/desktop/django/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

Now I am wondering if there really should be folders of 2 different python versions in there? Is that correct?

Comment: Since you are doing django, enter the virtual env then python manage.py shell and see what it is running

Comment: I know that I'm running on python 3.4, I use 'python3 manage.py ..." when I'm in the shell. But I am wondering if theres going to be a conflict when both python versions are in the python path.